# Terraform altering the infrastructure with change in the packer image

Tags: azure, terraform, devops, packer

I want to understand the change detection in the VMs when I create a new packer image

Created a new VM image on Azure using packer, created the VM using terraform. But I am not able to create a new infrastructure when the Packer image is changed

### Terraform Code:

```
variable "prefix" {
  default = "tfvmex"
}

variable "custom_image_name" {
  default = "developer-desktop-image"
}

variable "custom_image_resource_group_name" {
  default = "golden_image_rg"
}

data "azurerm_image" "custom" {
  name                = "${var.custom_image_name}"
  resource_group_name = "${var.custom_image_resource_group_name}"
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "main" {
  name     = "${var.prefix}-resources"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "main" {
  name                = "${var.prefix}-network"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = "${azurerm_resource_group.main.location}"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.main.name}"
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "internal" {
  name                 = "internal"
  resource_group_name  = "${azurerm_resource_group.main.name}"
  virtual_network_name = "${azurerm_virtual_network.main.name}"
  address_prefix       = "10.0.2.0/24"
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "main" {
  name                = "${var.prefix}-nic"
  location            = "${azurerm_resource_group.main.location}"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.main.name}"

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "testconfiguration1"
    subnet_id                     = "${azurerm_subnet.internal.id}"
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_managed_disk" "test" {
  name                 = "${azurerm_virtual_machine.main.name}-disk1"
  location             = "${azurerm_resource_group.main.location}"
  resource_group_name  = "${azurerm_resource_group.main.name}"
  storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
  create_option        = "Empty"
  disk_size_gb         = 10
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_data_disk_attachment" "test" {
  managed_disk_id    = "${azurerm_managed_disk.test.id}"
  virtual_machine_id = "${azurerm_virtual_machine.main.id}"
  lun                = "10"
  caching            = "ReadWrite"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "main" {
  name                  = "${var.prefix}-vm"
  location              = "${azurerm_resource_group.main.location}"
  resource_group_name   = "${azurerm_resource_group.main.name}"
  network_interface_ids = ["${azurerm_network_interface.main.id}"]
  vm_size               = "Standard_DS1_v2"

  # Uncomment this line to delete the OS disk automatically when deleting the VM
  # delete_os_disk_on_termination = true


  # Uncomment this line to delete the data disks automatically when deleting the VM
  # delete_data_disks_on_termination = true

  storage_image_reference {
    id = "${data.azurerm_image.custom.id}"
  }
  storage_os_disk {
    name              = "myosdisk1"
    caching           = "ReadWrite"
    create_option     = "FromImage"
    managed_disk_type = "Standard_LRS"
  }
  os_profile {
    computer_name  = "hostname"
    admin_username = "testadmin"
    admin_password = "p@$$w0rd@1234"
  }
  os_profile_linux_config {
    disable_password_authentication = false
  }
  tags = {
    environment = "staging"
  }
}
```

### Packer Code:

```
{
"variables": {
    "azure_subscription_id": "{{env `azure_subscription_id`}}",
    "azure_tennant_id": "{{env `azure_tennant_id`}}",
    "azure_application_id": "{{env `azure_application_id`}}",
    "azure_application_password": "{{env `azure_application_password`}}"
},
"builders": [{
    "type": "azure-arm",

    "client_id": "{{user `azure_application_id`}}",
    "client_secret": "{{user `azure_application_password`}}",
    "tenant_id": "{{user `azure_tennant_id`}}",
    "subscription_id": "{{user `azure_subscription_id`}}",

    "managed_image_name": "developer-desktop-image",
    "managed_image_resource_group_name": "golden_image_rg",

    "os_type": "linux",
    "image_publisher": "OpenLogic",
    "image_offer": "CentOS",
    "image_sku": "7.5",

    "location": "West Europe",
    "temp_resource_group_name": "tmp_image_rg",

    "location": "West Europe",
    "vm_size": "Standard_B2ms",
    "os_disk_size_gb": "250",    

    "azure_tags": {
       "dept": "Golden Image Build"
    }
}],
"provisioners": [
    {
    "type": "shell",
    "scripts": [
         "../scripts/install_ansible.sh"
      ]
    },
    {
    "type": "ansible-local",
    "playbook_dir": "../gold-image-playbook",
    "playbook_file": "../gold-image-playbook/provision.yml",
    "extra_arguments": [ "--extra-vars -vvvv"]
    },
    {
     "execute_command": "chmod +x {{ .Path }}; {{ .Vars }} sudo -E sh '{{ .Path }}'",
     "inline": [
       "/usr/sbin/waagent -force -deprovision+user && export HISTSIZE=0 && sync"
     ],
     "inline_shebang": "/bin/sh -x",
     "type": "shell"
   }]
}
```

I have a pipeline in Jenkins that builds the packer image to Azure. I have another pipeline that deploys a VM using the above image.

Please help me understand if I can use terraform to detect any changes in the Azure Image I create using packer.

I expect that any change in the packer image should be detected by terraform.

I get the following output.

```
Refreshing Terraform state in-memory prior to plan...
The refreshed state will be used to calculate this plan, but will not be
persisted to local or remote state storage.

azurerm_resource_group.main: Refreshing state... (ID: /subscriptions/2729dfbe-46bf-46a6-a4d6-...7132ff/resourceGroups/tfvmex-resources)
data.azurerm_image.custom: Refreshing state...
azurerm_virtual_network.main: Refreshing state... (ID: /subscriptions/2729dfbe-46bf-46a6-a4d6-...Network/virtualNetworks/tfvmex-network)
azurerm_subnet.internal: Refreshing state... (ID: /subscriptions/2729dfbe-46bf-46a6-a4d6-...tworks/tfvmex-network/subnets/internal)
azurerm_network_interface.main: Refreshing state... (ID: /subscriptions/2729dfbe-46bf-46a6-a4d6-...t.Network/networkInterfaces/tfvmex-nic)
azurerm_virtual_machine.main: Refreshing state... (ID: /subscriptions/2729dfbe-46bf-46a6-a4d6-...soft.Compute/virtualMachines/tfvmex-vm)
azurerm_managed_disk.test: Refreshing state... (ID: /subscriptions/2729dfbe-46bf-46a6-a4d6-...icrosoft.Compute/disks/tfvmex-vm-disk1)
azurerm_virtual_machine_data_disk_attachment.test: Refreshing state... (ID: /subscriptions/2729dfbe-46bf-46a6-a4d6-...es/tfvmex-vm/dataDisks/tfvmex-vm-disk1)

------------------------------------------------------------------------

No changes. Infrastructure is up-to-date.

This means that Terraform did not detect any differences between your
configuration and real physical resources that exist. As a result, no
actions need to be performed.
```

Please advise on the approach.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** The below answer is using an example for AWS, though all of should apply to Azure as well, using its own keywords.

The common practice is to generate images from Packer suffixed with some sort of version, such as a timestamp:

```
"ami_name": "my-packer-image-{{timestamp}}"
```

Then, at Terraform, a data source is defined to retrieve the image with a wildcard that matches all the versions along with the `most_recent` property set to `true`, like so:

```
data "aws_ami" "myimage" {
  most_recent = true

  filter {
    name   = "name"
    values = ["my-packer-image-*"]
  }

  owners = ["<aws-account-id-goes-here>"]
}
```

The instance will then be declared referencing this data source:

```
resource "aws_instance" "myinstance" {
  ami           = "${data.aws_ami.myimage.id}" 
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
}
```

When Packer rebuilds the image and creates a new one, with a new timestamp, thanks to the data source Terraform will be able to detect the new image version and will rebuild the instance again with that new image.

For the specific case of Azure, [azurerm_image](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/d/image.html) data source has a `name_regex` and `sort_descending` attributes available, that should allow you to achieve the same result. While choosing the version to use, bear in mind that Azure `sort_descending` is based on name and not on a date, which might affect what it considers the first.